# Is a union a standard-layout type itself?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a standard layout type like this:

```
struct sl_t
{
  int a;
};
```

And a union like this:

```
union un_t
{
  int b;
  double q;
};
```

Can I cast and use the union as the struct type? That is, may I assume that the union itself is a standard-layout type and the data is aligned at the start of the memory?

```
un_t obj;
sl_t * s = reinterpret_cast<sl_t*>(&obj);
s->a = 15;
assert( obj.b == 15 );
```

Or must I take the address of the variable in the union `&obj.b`?

Note that I'm already aware that if I store the struct inside the union the C++11 standard guarantees I may access both sl_t::a and un_t::b, referring to 9.5-1.

Comment: But... isn't `&obj.b` both shorter and safer?  I'm curious about your motivations.

Comment: I'd still actually need the reinterpret_cast around it. I'm mainly curious, but I do actually have a case where it'd be convenient to rely on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems alignment is your issue, look at `pragma pack`. The struct/union names just references the allocated memory-block, if st_t.a is displaced in the struct by adding more members, your cast will fail, but if it remains the first member it will work since all members of the union points to the same address as the union itself.

See section 9.2.17 - 21 of the C++-standard:
"A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa."

See also section 9.5 Unions:
"1. In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time. [ Note: One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence (9.2), and if an object of this standard-layout union type contains one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of standard-layout struct members; see 9.2. — end note ] The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its non-static data members. Each non-static data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a struct."

Comment: I'm interested in knowing, without any compiler extensions, whether it is valid.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: I expanded my answer, yes it is valid but only as I explained.

Comment: Your second comment, where in the standard does it actually guarantee the address of union members is the same as the address itself? That's what I've failed to find, but yes, that would make my conversion valid.  And yes, obviously if st_t.a is no longer the first member it won't work.

Comment: You have to allocate `sizeof(union)` and though the union is the size of its largest member, I still can't find a reference saying the other members share an address.  Note that I agree in practice (all known compilers) it is as you say.

Comment: I read those bits as well, I mention 9.5-1 in my question. Internally each member is standard layout, but that still doesn't imply the address of the union equals the address of its members.  That is, is the union itself a standard layout class if its members are all standard-layout?

Comment: Okay, I'm going to assume that 9.5 combined with 9-8 do state what I want. Clause 8 does seem to indicate a union contained standard layout classes is a standard layout union.  That's good enough for me.